# How to let a image cover another image?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want the crown icon cover the photo image, so I use `bottom`. to change the position.

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <Image
    source={CrownIcon}
    style={{ width: 28, height: 18, bottom: -7 }}
  />
  <Image
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }}
  />
</View>
```

But the result is the photo image cover the crown icon.

[image]

So I try to add `<View />` and use `position: 'absolute'`

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 32 }}>
    <Image
      source={CrownIcon}
      style={{ width: 28, height: 18 }}
    />
  </View>
  <Image
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }}
  />
</View>
```

The photo image still cover the crown icon.

[image]

How do I let the crown icon cover the photo image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem is with overlapping image

Just add zIndex : 5 to your image

```
 <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 32 , zIndex: 5 }}> 
        <Image
          source={CrownIcon}
          style={{ width: 28, height: 18 }}
        />
      </View>
      <Image
        source={{uri: image}}
        style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I haven't heard about `zIndex`. Learned it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageBackground`

.e.g.

```
<ImageBackground
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={your-style}
>
    <Image
        source={{uri: image}}
        style={your-style}
    />
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Yes, `<ImageBackground />` is a solution too, thanks.